# Testcontainers exception on startup

Tags: c#, docker, selenium-webdriver, testcontainers

Does anyone know why I sometimes get exception when I use Selenium together with Testcontainers. See below:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code: 'An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/session. The exception message was: An error occurred while sending the request.'
> Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
> Innermost exception    System.IO.IOException : The response ended prematurely.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__61.MoveNext()

This happens half the time when i run the following test constructor (C# / xUnit.net):

```cs
public DockerShould()
{
    var gridNetwork = new NetworkBuilder()
        .WithName("gridNetwork")
        .Build();

    const int SessionPort = 4444;
    var containerHub = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("selenium/hub:4.8")
        .WithName("selenium-hub")
        .WithPortBinding(4442, 4442)
        .WithPortBinding(4443, 4443)
        .WithPortBinding(SessionPort, SessionPort)
        .WithNetwork(gridNetwork)
        .Build();

    var firefoxEnvironment = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST", "selenium-hub"},
        {"SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT", "4442"},
        {"SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT", "4443"}
    };

    var containerFirefox = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("selenium/node-firefox:4.8")
        .WithEnvironment(firefoxEnvironment)
        .WithNetwork(gridNetwork)
        .Build();

    var firefoxVideoEnvironment = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME", "firefox"},
        {"FILE_NAME", "firefox.mp4"}
    };      
    
    var containerFirefoxVideo = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("selenium/video:ffmpeg-4.3.1-20230210")
        .WithNetwork(gridNetwork)            
        .WithEnvironment(firefoxVideoEnvironment)
        // .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(SessionPort))
        .Build();        
    
    gridNetwork.CreateAsync().Wait();
    containerHub.StartAsync().Wait();
    containerFirefox.StartAsync().Wait();
    containerFirefoxVideo.StartAsync().Wait();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    _remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444"), new FirefoxOptions());
}
```

The exception occurs when creating the new RemoteWebDriver. I've added a thread.sleep to give a bit of a delay before the variable is created. I'm not sure it's really helping much. Is there a more elegant way to ensure all containers are started up before attempting to create the web driver (which i'm assuming is the problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration has a few shortcomings. I am uncertain as to which one is ultimately causing the issue, but I have provided a working example below. The crucial parts have been commented. Please note that the example does not incorporate a [wait strategy](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/wait_strategies/) to determine the readiness of the container or the service inside it. That is an aspect that you will still need to address. But first lets take a look at some basics.

1. Please consider reading the article [Consuming the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/consuming-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern). Testcontainers for .NET utilizes the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP). I noticed that you tend to block the asynchronous context frequently.
2. You do not need to bind ports for container-to-container communication.
3. Avoid using fixed port bindings such as `WithPortBinding(4444, 4444)`. To prevent port conflicts, assign a random host port by using `WithPortBinding(4444, true)` and retrieve it from the container instance using `GetMappedPublicPort(4444)`.
4. Do not use fixed container names for the same reason mentioned in 3. Use `WithNetworkAliases(string)` instead.
5. Do not use `localhost` to access services running inside containers. The endpoint varies according to the Docker environment. Use the `Hostname` property instead.

```cs
public sealed class StackOverflow : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private const ushort WebDriverPort = 4444;

    private readonly INetwork _network;

    private readonly IContainer _selenium;

    private readonly IContainer _firefox;

    private readonly IContainer _ffmpg;

    public StackOverflow()
    {
        _network = new NetworkBuilder()
            .Build();

        _selenium = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage("selenium/hub:4.8")

            // Use random assigned host ports to access the service running inside the containers.
            .WithPortBinding(WebDriverPort, true)
            .WithNetwork(_network)

            // Use a network-alias to communication between containers.
            .WithNetworkAliases(nameof(_selenium))
            .Build();

        _firefox = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage("selenium/node-firefox:4.8")
            .WithEnvironment("SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST", nameof(_selenium))
            .WithEnvironment("SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT", "4442")
            .WithEnvironment("SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT", "4443")
            .WithNetwork(_network)
            .WithNetworkAliases(nameof(_firefox))
            .Build();

        _ffmpg = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage("selenium/video:ffmpeg-4.3.1-20230210")
            .WithEnvironment("DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME", nameof(_firefox))
            .WithEnvironment("FILE_NAME", nameof(_firefox) + ".mp4")
            .WithNetwork(_network)
            .WithNetworkAliases(nameof(_ffmpg))
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _network.CreateAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // You can await Task.WhenAll(params Task[]) too.
        await _selenium.StartAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _firefox.StartAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _ffmpg.StartAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _selenium.DisposeAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _firefox.DisposeAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _ffmpg.DisposeAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _network.DeleteAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Question()
    {
        // TODO: The container configurations mentioned above lack a wait strategy. It is crucial that you add a wait strategy to each of them to determine readiness (afterwards remove this line).
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Use the Hostname property instead of localhost. Get the random assigned host port with GetMappedPublicPort(ushort).
        var webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new UriBuilder(Uri.UriSchemeHttp, _selenium.Hostname, _selenium.GetMappedPublicPort(WebDriverPort)).Uri, new FirefoxOptions());
        Assert.NotNull(webDriver.SessionId);
    }
}
```

**Update**:

Meanwhile, there is a Testcontainers [WebDriver](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/8b958d36fca4a5a59675177e407dad5517bdd8be/tests/Testcontainers.WebDriver.Tests/WebDriverContainerTest.cs#L47-L54) module (depends on Selenium) that sets everything up.